# Next.js | Error request for '.chunk-`X`' is not in cache

Tags: node.js, reactjs, typescript, next.js

Hello guys my code used to work fine until recently, I used getStaticProps and a cache time of 5 days now im getting the error at the title.

More detailed error:

```
error - node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:123
        this.module.instantiate();
                    ^
Error: request for './chunk-NO6MRLPK.mjs' is not in cache
    at ModuleJob._instantiate (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:123:21)
    at async ModuleJob.run (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:189:5)
    at async Promise.all (index 0)
    at async ESMLoader.import (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:530:24)
    at async importModuleDynamicallyWrapper (node:internal/vm/module:438:15) {
  code: 'ERR_VM_MODULE_LINK_FAILURE',
  page: '/'
}
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "unipos-web",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint",
    "lint:fix": "next lint --fix",
    "ts-lint": "tsc --noEmit --incremental --watch",
    "format": "prettier --check --ignore-path .gitignore .",
    "format:fix": "prettier --write --ignore-path .gitignore ."
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@chakra-ui/icons": "^2.0.3",
    "@chakra-ui/react": "^2.4.3",
    "@emotion/react": "^11.10.5",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.10.5",
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.8.5",
    "@tanstack/react-query": "^4.20.4",
    "@tanstack/react-query-devtools": "^4.20.4",
    "axios": "^1.2.1",
    "ethers": "^5.7.2",
    "formik": "^2.2.9",
    "framer-motion": "^7.6.7",
    "html5-qrcode": "^2.3.4",
    "next": "^13.0.7",
    "next-redux-wrapper": "^8.0.0",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-error-boundary": "^3.1.4",
    "react-qr-code": "^2.0.7",
    "react-redux": "^8.0.2",
    "react-select": "^5.5.0",
    "react-web-share": "^2.0.2",
    "siwe": "^1.1.6",
    "socket.io-client": "^4.5.3",
    "wagmi": "^0.9.2",
    "yup": "^0.32.11"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "^18.0.3",
    "@types/react": "^18.0.15",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.0.6",
    "eslint": "^8.30.0",
    "eslint-config-next": "13.1.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.5.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^4.2.1",
    "prettier": "^2.8.1",
    "typescript": "^4.9.4"
  },
  "overrides": {
    "siwe": {
      "ethers": "$ethers"
    }
  }
}
```

next.config.cjs

```
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
module.exports = {
  reactStrictMode: false,
  env: {
    ENV: process.env.ENV,
    INFURA_API_KEY: process.env.INFURA_API_KEY,
  },
}
```

Things I have tried:

- Remove .next & node_modules & package-lock.json
- Remove the getStaticProps from my code ( and any related code ( Such as react-query) )
- Remove .next & node_modules & package-lock.json
- Remove the getStaticProps from my code ( and any related code ( Such as react-query) )
- Turned my next.config.js to next.config.mjs
- Resolved all TS and ESLint errors
- Tried to run the version which did not have any cache or ssr ( even this version gives out the same error )
- Tried running a fresh create-next-app ( this works )
- Cleaned npm cache
- Rebooted
- Cleaned browser cache
- Nvm install latest node version
- Downgraded to Next 13.1.0 and then 13.0.7
- Tried running the dev server on different ports
- Build has the same error
- Tried on Incognito

Answer (score 1):

I have managed to solve this issue by downgrading to:

```
"@chakra-ui/icons": "2.0.3",
"@chakra-ui/react": "2.4.3",
"next": "13.0.7"
```

Also I had to be sure I was importing all Chakra components from `'@chakra-ui/react'`